# Is it possible to fix an element with unknown height just below the border of the screen?

Tags: css

I'm building a thing that's going to slide out from the bottom of the screen . I don't know it's height.

If I knew the height I could do

```
position: fixed;
bottom: -200px //height of object
```

I slide it out using css-animations and it's going to slide to `bottom: 0` therefore I can't use `top: 100%;` to hide the object either. Are there any other options?

Comment: have you tried `top:100%`?

Comment: well, I wrote so in my question :) The problem is that as I want the element to transition to bottom:0 I can't use top

Comment: I think you can try using `transform:translateY(-100%)` (set the `top:100%`) to slide it in. Without knowing the height, that's the only solution.

Comment: i think it's possible only with js if the height is unknown

Comment: @omegaiori no, using transform can solve it, see the previous comment of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my proposed solution. Use translateY to move it.

**CSS**

```
.slidingthing {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100%;

    /* or margin-top in your case?
    margin-top: 100% */

    height: 100px; // or whatever
    width: 100px; // or whatever
    transform: translateY(-100%); // add other browser vendor prefixes
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/vKW65/4/

Comment: you are a really clever person!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a parent node

```
parent:{
    position: fixed;
    top: 100%;
}
child {

}
```

then use margin-top from 0 to -100%

Comment: no, `margin-top` is not relative to the `height`, it is relative to the `width` so `margin-top:-100%` will be `-100% of width` not `-100% of height`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number that's much larger, like `bottom: -2000px`; you may also add `overflow:hidden` to make sure the scroll bar doesn't appear once the element is moved out of the view, provided you otherwise don't want to make use of it on your page.

Comment: This will make the animation move very fast.

Comment: are you happy to use javascript / jQuery or only interested in a pure css solution?